# CS50p - PSet4 - Adieu - Exit code 1

Tags: python, compiler-errors, compilation, cs50

So, I have supposedly finished my code for the Adieu exercise from Problem Set 4. I tested all of the inputs that check50 uses and I get the right feedback from my code. However, when I run check50 it throws a ":( input of EOF halts program; expected exit code 0, not 1", which, to my understanding, means the code isn't compiling properly. After that it's not able to check all of the following scenarios, although that makes sense if the code is not compiling.

```
from icecream import ic
import sys

def main():
    names = []
    txt = "Adieu, adieu, to"
    while True:
        try: names.append(input())
        except EOFError:
            for i in range(len(names)):
                if i == 0: txt = txt + " " + names[i]
                elif i == len(names)-1: txt = txt + " and " + names[i]
                else: txt = txt + ", " + names[i]
                print(txt)
            break

main()
```

Ignore the ic and sys imports, I just used them to test the code, but it was failing even before importing them so it has nothing to do with the issue. I remember that a couple of versions of code before this one I didn't have this issue, although I can't recall what happened between then and now (The code didn´t work then, otherwise I wouldn't have touched it)

I made a lot of changes in syntax, nesting and running order, but nothing seems to make check50 like it.

Comment: I recommend you not format your code like that.

Comment: @JonSG I'm not sure of what you mean by "like that", although I would like to know to change it in the future. If you mean having the main part of the code inside of the exception, it was not like that at first, it was just my last attempt to compile before uploading the code here.

Comment: Sorry, I mean placing the code on as few lines as possible

Comment: Unclear what “Problem Set 4” is, or what this code is supposed to do, or what it actually does. When posting a question, you should include a [mcve], including all relevant details: not just code, but sample input, expected vs actual behavior, errors, etc. Right now it’s some code and an error.

Comment: @DavidMakogon thx for the feedback on my post. It's one of the first times I use the platform so I'm still not aware on how to make a proper post. I already solved the problem here, but as soon as I have some time I'll update with a comment including all of the details for it to be useful to anyone that comes afterwards. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, but my reasoning to get to it might be incorrect:
An exit code 1 means there was an abnormal termination of the execution, which probably hides a runtime error. I looked around at my code and found that, even though I tested it and didn't get an error, there was a possible runtime error hidden here:

```
while True:
    try: names.append(input())
    except EOFError: break
```

If the user exits with ctrl+d the input function gets ended prematurely, meaning the append operation either doesn't work properly or just doesn't append anything to the list. Because of this, when I later call `names[i]` there's nothing for it to call, as the list is empty.

I added a `sys.exit()` that runs when the list is empty to prevent it from running the following lines. It ended up looking like this:

```
import sys

def main():
    names = []
    txt = "Adieu, adieu, to"
    while True:
        try: names.append(input())
        except EOFError: break
    if len(names) == 0: sys.exit()
    for i in range(len(names)):
        if i == 0: txt = txt + " " + names[i]
        elif i == len(names)-1: txt = txt + " and " + names[i]
        else: txt = txt + ", " + names[i]
    print(txt)

if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

As i said, this worked but I'm not sure if my analysis on it is correct, so any corrections are welcome.